# Can't see whole object in StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic, stackpanel

I am a newbie in WPF trying to create his first normal project which is a notes application.
Every note is linked to a `button` and I thought it'll look beautiful in `StackPanel`.
I am dynamically creating `button`s within `StackPanel`, but the problem is that when I scroll down the list of `Button`s last `Button` can't be seen fully. I thought it was because of the `Margin` and tried to adjust it, but it didn't help, also `auto` `Height` and `Width` didn't help. `StackPanel` is within `ScrollViewer` and when I reach the end of `ScrollBar` I just can see half of last button ?

Here is `StackPanel`'s XAML code:

```
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="50 -50 50 5" >
                <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonPanel"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

That is how I create `Button`:

```
            dynamicTextBox.Add(SearchNotes); 
            dynamicTextBox[index_of_buttons] = new TextBox();
            Grid.SetRow(dynamicTextBox[index_of_buttons], 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(dynamicTextBox[index_of_buttons], 0);
            this.ButtonPanel.Children.Add(dynamicTextBox[index_of_buttons]);
            dynamicTextBox[index_of_buttons].IsReadOnly = false;
            dynamicTextBox[index_of_buttons].Text = "";
```

Where `dynamicTextBox` is `List<>`  of  `TextBox`es to which is applied Template(I think it is not necessary to see Template to resolve the problem)

This is how it looks like:
[Can't see the whole button(the last one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIi1g.png)

So I wanna see the whole button.

Comment: Use a listbox instead of all that. Template out the rows from a bound collection of viewmodels. Never use large margins to position anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy wrote in the comment section, `ListBox` is best solution for this problem.
I tried this one to make it look like exactly same as it was in StackPanel

Xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxOfButtons" Background="#404040" BorderThickness="0" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="50 -20 50 5">
</ListBox>
```

C#:

```
var txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.Template = FindResource("TemplateForTextBox") as ControlTemplate;
ListBoxOfButtons.Items.Add(txtBox);
```

[This is how last button looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKOxs.png)